# Loading a trained Rasa NLU model takes more time

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I have trained a RASA NLU model with the following config

```
language: en
pipeline:
- name: "pretrained_embeddings_convert"
```

This configuration defaults to the list of components,

```
language: "en"

pipeline:
- name: "SpacyNLP"
- name: "SpacyTokenizer"
- name: "SpacyFeaturizer"
- name: "RegexFeaturizer"
- name: "CRFEntityExtractor"
- name: "EntitySynonymMapper"
- name: "SklearnIntentClassifier"
```

Also I have tried all the other readily available configs like `supervised_embeddings and pretrained_embeddings_spacy` and custom configs as well. All of it takes 6~9 seconds of load time for instantiating the Trainer object. Similarly when I tried to load the persisted model for inference,

```
interpreter = Interpreter.load('../path_to_trained_model')
```

again it takes almost of same 6~9 seconds for loading it. Is there anyway that this can be mitigated ? or I am doing something wrong ? Because I want to serve these models on demand, which requires a faster load time.

Comment: While debugging I tried to find the load time of each component. The first component only took ~ 6-9 seconds rest of them are taking just micro seconds. Then I tried a non time taking component individually with ComponentBuilder which surprisingly took ~ 6-9 seconds, so my guess is that there is something else causing this delay.

Answer (score 0):

`supervised_embeddings` (see [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/choosing-a-pipeline/#section-supervised-embeddings-pipeline)) is the pipeline that will have the shortest load time, because it doesn't load up any pre-trained word embeddings.

`pretained_embeddings_convert` and `pretrained_embeddings_spacy` both load up word embeddings at start up (the `ConveRT` and `spacy` embeddings respectively), which are quite large in size and therefore take some time to load.

So if a fast load time is important, I would recommend using `supervised_embeddings`. However, once a model is loaded the inference time is relatively fast, so you only need to wait those few seconds once.

PS: if you haven't already please join our community [forum](https://forum.rasa.com), where questions like these are answered frequently

Comment: Hey @Akela I have asked the same question in the Rasa Community and GitHub as well. Thanks for taking your time to explain your answer. As you pointed out for the other methods word embedding will be loading at the start. Here I use SpaCy model, which on loading individually takes just ~0.7 secs, but here it is taking much time. But this happens in the *supervised embeddings* method as well. I went through the code base and found that the delays happens on the first component loading, irrespective of the component and the method (spacy/supervised embedding) used.

Comment: How big is your model?

Comment: As I already mentioned it is happening with the supervised embeddings as well. So it doesn't depend on my model size as of now. By the way I am using the default spacy model only.

Comment: I meant how big is your trained rasa model (in MB, when saved)? Not the spacy model

Comment: Hey Akela, it is 38 MB.